# Help with size of folder path

Tags: c#, .net, file-io, filesize

i am trying to write an application to calculate the size of a set of shares using the following code. The issue however is that as the search gets deep in to the shares, the file path variable in the loop becomes to large an exception gets thrown and therefore cant continue. I found something which says that combining `@"\\?\"` allows the charachter count to increase but i cant figure out how to append it properly. My share takes the form of `\\server\name` as you would expect.

Thanks.

```
try
{
    //Checks if the path is valid or not
    if (!Directory.Exists(folder))
    {
        return folderSize;
    }
    else
    {
        try
        {
            foreach (string filePath in Directory.GetFiles(folder))
            {
                if (File.Exists(filePath))
                {
                    FileInfo finfo = new FileInfo(filePath);
                    folderSize += finfo.Length;
                }
            }

            foreach (string dir in Directory.GetDirectories(folder))
                folderSize += GetDirectorySize(dir);
        }
        catch (NotSupportedException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Unable to calculate folder size: {0}", e.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

**exception thrown after trying suggested answers**

```
    'A first chance exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
'ShareSizes.vshost.exe' (Managed): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Configuration\2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Configuration.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
Could not find file 'Shortcut to fileName'.
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.FileInfo.get_Length()
   at ShareSizes.Form1.button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Documents and Settings\...line 50
```

Comment: How did you try to combine your current path with these characters?

Comment: String s = Path.combine( "@"\\?\", filePath)

Comment: and what about `s = @"\\?\" + filePath`? Does this work?

Comment: no because i cant get the escape charachters to work :/

Comment: there are no escape characters here... so what do you mean?

Comment: Anyway, `if (File.Exists(filePath))` makes no sense.

Comment: file 'Shortcut to fileName' where is that file? what does it point to? open the shortcut file in notepad and look, if you move that file away for the time being does the program work otherwise or does it keep failing on something else?

Answer (score 1):

You could just do something like this:

```
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(rootFolder);
foreach (FileInfo finfo in di.GetFiles("*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories) 
{
   folderSize += finfo.Length;  
}
```

Comment: it throws an exception if there is a shortcut it cant find the parent for

Answer (score 0):

try this instead:

```
string path = @"\\Server\Share";

System.IO.DirectoryInfo dInfo = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(path);
long totalSize = 0;

foreach (FileInfo fInfo in dInfo.GetFiles("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)) {
    totalSize += fInfo.Length;

}

Console.Out.WriteLine(totalSize.ToString());
```

Comment: it throws an exception if there is a shortcut it cant find the parent for

Comment: you mean a shortcut to a file that no longer exists? because it works perfectly fine for me with dead shortcuts

Comment: i have updated my original post with the exception being thrown

Comment: odd, everything I have tried including folder permissions and access rights and pointing to many files that dont exist, all works fine for me.

Comment: its because the fileinfo fie path is too long - which is the same issue i previously had